# I am unable to point paragon to the Windows ADK (so as to create bootable media)

Tags: windows-10, paragon

What file(s) exactly is Paragon hard disk manager looking for - when specifying adk?

It's not working for me

I have this from an ADK I downloaded

[image]

Yet paragon still says that C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10  path does not seem valid

[image]

As a workaround for now, I would consider paragon's option to do a linux bootable, but paragon says that requires a license.

In answer to Tetsujin's comment, I tried `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\`  and got the same error

Comment: The WinPE is an add-on to Windows ADK.  I am in the process of writing an answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah same error

Comment: I think Ramhound may be correct re addon, i'm trying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What file(s) exactly is Paragon hard disk manager looking for - when specifying ask?

In order to create a WinPE ISO, you must have two things installed, if you are using the Windows ADK for Windows 10 version 1809 or later.

1. The current Windows ADK must be installed.
2. You must also install the WinPE Addon for the version of the Windows ADK you have installed.

> The files you need to create WinPE media are included in the Winpe Add-on to the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit. To create WinPE media, you'll have to install the ADK with the Deployment tools option, and then install the WindowsPE addon kit.

You can avoid the second required by using the Windows ADK for Windows 10 version 1803 or earlier.

> In previous versions, WinPE is included in the Windows ADK.

Source: [Download and Install the Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/download-winpe--windows-pe#download-and-install-the-windows-adk)

> you wrote "you'll have to install the ADK with the Deployment tools option, and then install the WindowsPE addon kit." <-- i'm not sure about that but I found that once I got the WinPE Addon EXE, adkwinpesetup.exe Then I installed that, then I clicked that button that i'd clicked before again, and this time it gave no error and got into the next stage of the installation.,

The only reason it worked, after you installed the Add-on, is because you didn't have the Windows ADK WinPE Add-on installed the first time you tried to create the WinPE ISO.

> 'm not sure what is meant by " To create WinPE media, you'll have to install the ADK with the Deployment tools option, " in your answer though 'cos I didn't need to tick any 'deployment' option. I will have a look at what the options are again once i have completed this ISO creation

Those were actually Microsoft's instructions.  The deployment tools are part of the previous versions of the Windows ADK that that included WinPE.  **The particular statement only applies if you are installing Windows 10 ADK for Windows 10 version 1803 or earlier.**